# why my redis CPU usage raises up to 200% or more high?

Tags: redis

As far as I know, redis uses the single thread mode, but my redis CPU usage can raise up to 200% or more. I neither enable the snapshot nor aof. What's the cause maybe? How can I figure out ?

Thanks
Leo

Comment: Have you looked at similar questions such as: http://serverfault.com/questions/762268/how-to-troubleshoot-redis-high-cpu-usage-and-how-to-limit-redis-cpu-usage

Comment: Explain how you use Redis and probably you'll answer your problem yourself :D